# Where do I find the 'Edmonds' class in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using the networkx framework for graph manipulation in python 2.7. For obtaining an optimal branching (arborescence) from a directed graph, I wanted to use the Edmond's algorithm.

On networkx' website, one can find an implementation of that [algorithm](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/_modules/networkx/algorithms/tree/branchings.html). 
The class 'Edmonds' is also listed in the [reference](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.tree.branchings.Edmonds.html#networkx.algorithms.tree.branchings.Edmonds).

However, I can't find the actual module which contains this class. Is it not an official class contained in the release?

Comment: quick comment - I've just added instructions to my answer for how to install the development version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your links are to the 'development' part of networkx (check the url), so I don't think it's in the standard release yet.

Probably your best option is to copy the relevant code into a file in your working directory and import it separately.  Otherwise, look to download the development version of networkx.

More details: 
http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/

According to https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/install.html

> You can install the development version (at github.com) with
>
> pip install git://github.com/networkx/networkx.git#egg=networkx